# jquery ajax click passes a number to a php file. Need jquery to pass a text response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting a response, but as a number. How can I get the actual **text name**?

```
echo "<td><a href='#' class='js-load-more' data-playername='"
.($players['first_name'])."'>".($players['first_name'])." ".
($players['last_name'])."</a></td>";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-load-more").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).data('playername');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test2.php',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: 'false',
            data: 'name',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#info').html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**RETURNS A NUMBER "1".  Why not a name?:**

```
<?php
  $test = isset($_GET['name']);
  echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `isset()` returns a `boolean` value.

```
isset($_GET['name']); // returns true or false

$_GET['name']; // returns the playername or undefined index
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$test = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
echo $test;
```